# DAX MTD Measure to create by day of month chart (Replicate running [Function] in)

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I am look to create a measure that allows me to use a custom function to plot a cumulative value which is able to be plotted as:

day of month in vs running [Function] in, split by months.

The simplest version (doable by using the chart option Running total in) which I am stuck trying to replicate using measures.

This is very easy in PowerBI using the Day Index of time hierarchy, but I am unable to get it to populate in powerpivot

The current formula is:

```
MTDTotalCount:=CALCULATE(COUNT([Id]),DATESMTD([Date]))
```

[image: Current vs Required]

I need to keep this as flexible as possible as i need to plot similar using other custom functions

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you would need a column in your Date-table which holds the DayOfMonth (1-31) and another one to hold the MonthName
then you can simply use the DayOfMonth as X-Axis, the MonthName in the Legend

Comment: Unfortunately this prevents you creating running/ MTD totals and other calculations in your measure

Comment: actually it should not. You just need to ensure that, in the final visual, the selections refer to a single date. So if you use DateOfMonth you also need to have Month and Year in the context somewhere (rows, columns or filters)